# Summing over an index in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sum

I have a large index list and a large parameter dictionary. The len of `some_dict` is almost 1 million. I am trying to create a new dictionary using this 4-indexed dictionary and gather it into 3-indices. I also have the list `RPS` containing the list of indices (in 3-tuple format), which has a len of ~0.5 million. This current loop has not ended after some good while. Is there any Pythonic trick to boost things up?

```
mynewdict= {(r,p,s): sum(some_dict[r,p,s,t]/another_dict[t] 
                         for (r,p,s,t) in RPST) for (r,p,s) in RPS}
```

For a minimal example, let:

```
RPS = [(1, 13, 37),
 (1, 13, 38),
 (1, 13, 39),
 (1, 13, 40)]

RPST = [(1, 13, 37, 9027),
 (1, 13, 37, 9028),
 (1, 13, 37, 9058),
 (1, 13, 38, 9027),
 (1, 13, 38, 9028),
 (1, 13, 38, 9058),
 (1, 13, 39, 9027),
 (1, 13, 39, 9028),
 (1, 13, 40, 9027),
 (1, 13, 40, 9028)]

some_dict = { (1, 13, 37, 9027): 1,
 (1, 13, 37, 9028): 1,
 (1, 13, 37, 9058): 1,
 (1, 13, 38, 9027): 1,
 (1, 13, 38, 9028): 1,
 (1, 13, 38, 9058): 1,
 (1, 13, 39, 9027): 1,
 (1, 13, 39, 9028): 1,
 (1, 13, 40, 9027): 1,
 (1, 13, 40, 9028): 1}

another_dict = {9027: 2, 9028: 2, 9058: 2}
```

Comment: We will need a [mcve] including sample data to be able to provide any kind of useful insights.

Comment: @DeepSpace added an example.

Comment: With this small example, I am also able to see that my coding is not correct for what I would like to do. Essentially, mynewdict should be {(1, 13, 37): 1.5,
 (1, 13, 38): 1.5,
 (1, 13, 39): 1.0,
 (1, 13, 40): 1.0 }. But, they all return 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution for future reference:

```
RPSTdict = {(r,p,s):[] for (r,p,s) in RPS}
for (r,p,s,t) in RPST:
    RPSTdict[r,p,s].append(t)
mynewdict = {(r,p,s): sum(some_dict[r,p,s,t]/another_dict[t]
                          for t in RPSTdict[r,p,s]) for (r,p,s) in RPS}
```